# EFI partition between two major partitions

Tags: partitioning

I have an Asus tuf fx55dt laptop with a 256GB SSD that has Windows installed on it and a 1TB hard drive as well.

These events that took place.

1. I installed Ubuntu by creating a 300GB partition on my HDD.
2. Ubuntu was not booting up without my charger connected, so I decided to remove it.
3. Ubuntu was installed in a 292GB partition and a 500MB EFI partition was also made on my HDD.
4. I deleted the Ubuntu partition and an unallocated space of 292GB was made.

Then I tried to extend my 640GB partition in order to have my full HDD space back, but my 640GB partition did not extend to take up the 292GB unallocated space because the 500MB EFI partition is in between the two major partitions. Also my 640GB partition turned into a simple volume from a primary one.

So now I have a C drive (SSD) with my Windows installed and having a separate EFI partition of its own  and a D drive (HDD) that has no OS on it, but has a 500MB EFI partition in between my major partitions.

Also I think my booting still takes place through the D drive EFI partition because whenever I boot into my PC first grub shows up followed by the Windows bootloader.

I need to get my HDD space back.

Comment: You are supposed to only have one ESP - efi system partition per drive. But can have multiple FAT32 partitions and they may have boot folders & files. Best to only have one, but there are some exceptions. Post this: `sudo parted -l`